# Stand Alone Components with no NgModel

Tags: angular

i created a new header component but how can i use  in bootstrapApplication fnuction can only take 2 params

```
`import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { headerComponent } from './app/header/header.component';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig )
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
`
`<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularEkart</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-header></app-header>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>`


`import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector:'app-header',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [Headers],
    template:'<h2>app-header</h2>',
})

export class headerComponent{
}`
```

i am new to angular and i know it's an easy question but i can't find any resources to stand alone components in angular 20

Answer (score 1):

you can bootstrap several applications on the page (header component and app component). but it would be a little unusual and will cause a lot of limitations for your components communication.

more appropriate way is to have AppComponent as a root of the application and all other components would be rendered inside of it

```
// app.component.html
<app-header></app-header>
<main>
 ...other content...
</main>
```

```
// app.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  ...
  imports: [headerComponent]
})
```

Comment: but how to make the app component see the header component ?

Comment: @AhmedAlaa I've added it to the answer. but in reality IDE with angular language service should be able to provide all such hints for you and even provide options to autoimport required components